# Application crashes in GDB but not when running normally, crash occurs in libcrypto

Tags: qt, ssl, arm, gdb, webkit

I have Qt application that is displaying a WebView (webkit based).  I am attempting to debug it using gdb.  When I run the application through gdb it crashes almost immediately. The application runs without issues when executed outside of gdb.

The reason for the crash is:

```
Thread 1 "myapp" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x4a4d9a88 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.2
```

Since the error is SIGILL is it possible that gdb is loading the lib from the wrong path?

The application is really simple, just displays a WebView at specific URL:

```cpp
    ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->setUrl(QUrl(urlString));
```

The application crashes in gdb after the line above is executed.

The environment is an embedded system running linux on an arm architecture:

```
Linux hh4 3.1.10-2.8.5+g841700f8a2ea #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 3 18:48:07 UTC 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Any help in understanding why the app is crashing in gdb is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GDB loading the wrong library is a possibility.

An easy way to find out is to set a breakpoint on `main()` - by which point you'd expect the library to memory-mapped into the process.

You can probably use GDB to check, alternatively, get a shell on the target system and run

`losf -p <process_id>`

This will list all open file-handles owned by the process - including all shared libraries that are memory mapped.

If you are somehow using the development host's libraries this would definitely explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the lsof suggestion, but unfortunately the library path is correct.